# Getting error in installing mongeez plugin

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm trying to install mongeez plugin and I get the following error,
I have included ,
plugins{
..
 compile ':mongeez:0.2.3'
..
}
in the BuildConfig.groovy

Error creating bean with name 'grails.mongeez.MongeezController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongeez': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongo' is defined
.....
.....
....
....
.....
.....

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongeez': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongo' is defined

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm able to install the plugin by adding mongeez as a dependency instead of a plugin.

BuildConfig.groovy

 dependencies {
......
.....
compile 'org.mongeez:mongeez:0.9.6'
.....
......
}

Contents of  migrations folder(Change logs)
I have grails-app/migrations/test.js 
       grails-app/migrations/mongeez.xml

This is my mongeez.xml

<changeFiles>
    <file path="test.js"/>
</changeFiles>

This is my test.js

db.movie.insert({
    "name":"tutorials point"
});


I have written a groovy script as follows,


import com.mongodb.Mongo
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
import org.mongeez.Mongeez

includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

target(updateMongo: "Update the mongo DB!") {
    println "The script is about to run"

    def host = 'localhost'
    def port = 27017
    def databaseName = 'reporting'

    Mongeez mongeez = new Mongeez()
    mongeez.setFile(new ClassPathResource("/migrations/mongeez.xml"))
    mongeez.setMongo(new Mongo(host, port))
    mongeez.setDbName(databaseName)
    mongeez.process()

    println "The script just ran"
}
setDefaultTarget(updateMongo)




When I run the above script both the print statements are getting executed.
A mongeez collection also got created in my reporting db but the contents of test.js(movie collection) is not reflected in my mongodb , i.e movie collection is not getting created.

Please suggest me if I'm missing something.
```

Comment: Where do I need to put my changeset and mongeez files? I have them under, grails-app/migrations folder

Answer (score 0):

```
Got mongeez plugin working by replacing ClassPathResource with FileSystemResource.

Mongeez mongeez = new Mongeez()
 mongeez.setFile(new FileSystemResource(path)) // Give the path to your mongeez.xml
 mongeez.setMongo(new Mongo(properties.host, properties.port))
 mongeez.setDbName(databaseName)
 mongeez.process()
```